# ArrayList with User Input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Previously created an array of shoppingItems called ShoppingList. Each shoppingitem is entered by the user and is asked for the name, priority, price, and quantity. Now I am trying to do this same thing with an arraylist but I am having trouble.

This was my main when i had the array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShoppingList go = new ShoppingList();
    go.getElement();
    go.Sort();
    System.out.println("hello");
    go.displayResults();
}
```

and the getElement method was this:

```
public void getElement(){
    System.out.println("You can add seven items to purchase when prompted ");
    shoppingList = new ShoppingItem[numItems]; //creation of new array object
    for (int i = 0; i<= numItems - 1; i++) {
        shoppingList[i] = new ShoppingItem(); //shopping item objects created
        System.out.println("Enter data for the shopping item " + i);
        shoppingList[i].readInput();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now with the arraylist, I am just lost.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ShoppingItem>ShoppingList = new ArrayList<ShoppingItem>();
    ShoppingList //how do i call the getElement which then calls readInput()?
}
```

Thank you!! I fully understand that now. I used a bubblesort previously to sort the items by priority:

```
public void Sort(){
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    ShoppingItem tmp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for(int i = 0; i < shoppingList.length - j; i++) {
            if (shoppingList[i].getItemPriority() > shoppingList[i+1].getItemPriority()) {
                tmp = shoppingList[i];
                shoppingList[i] = shoppingList[i+1];
                shoppingList[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can still use this method, right? Just certain things would change for example.. .length would be .size()? Or am I not able to do this?

Comment: You're implementing it in two different ways; in the first version you had an instance variable as the array--why not just do the same thing with the `ArrayList` for now?

Comment: You can use `Collections.sort(shoppingList)` to sort a `List`.  You do not want to use the bubble sort code you've posted.  If you want to use it then you can use `shoppingList.toArray(new ShoppingItem[shoppingList.size()])` to get the array from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ArrayList works like an array, but is dynamically sized. Instead of someArray[2] to get an element, you'd use someArrayList.get(2).. And to add elements (to the end of an array list), just call someArrayList.add(newElementHere). So I've changed your code (into just 1 method) that create a list of ShoppingItems called shoppingList (you had this part), then it does the for loop for 7 items. Each time it creates a new instance of a ShoppingItem, does the readInput method on that, and then adds it to the end of the shoppingList. I'd consider making a new class called ShoppingList that encapsulates the ArrayList and provides methods for you to call (like askForItems(), sort(), display(), etc), but this code below should get you started hopefully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<ShoppingItem> shoppingList = new ArrayList<ShoppingItem>();

    System.out.println("You can add seven items to purchase when prompted ");
    for (int i = 0; i <7; i++) {
        ShoppingItem item = new ShoppingItem(); //shopping item objects created
        System.out.println("Enter data for the shopping item " + i);
        item.readInput();
        shoppingList.add(item);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```